# Connection pooling with SQLServerXADataSource

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, jdbc

The documentation of the `SQLServerXADataSource` interface, says that it provides connection pooling and whenever a client is done with the connection, should call the `close()` method; in this case the connection won't be closed but returned to the pool. I'm trying this, but next time I'm trying to get a connection it says the connection is already closed. How can I implement the connection pooling using this interface?

The class that provides the connection is:

```
public class ConnectionPool {
   SQLServerXADataSource ds;
   Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
   Connection connection = null;

   public ConnectionPool(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    ds = new SQLServerXADataSource();
    boolean res = Config.load(inputStream);
    if (res) {
        ds.setServerName(Config.SQL_SERVER());
        ds.setDatabaseName(Config.SQL_DB_NAME());
        ds.setIntegratedSecurity(Config.SQL_INTEGRATED_SECURITY());
        ds.setPortNumber(Config.SQL_PORT());
        if (!Config.SQL_INTEGRATED_SECURITY()) {
            ds.setUser(Config.SQL_USERNAME());
            ds.setPassword(new String(dec.decode(Config.SQL_USER_PASSWORD())));
           }
       } else {
           throw new Exception("Failed to load parameters.");
       }
       connection = ds.getConnection();
   }

   public Connection getConnection() throws SQLServerException {
       return this.connection;
   }
}
```

After creating the object of ConnectionPool (when the user is logged in), I save it as a session attribute so that the servlets can get it when they need it.

Can you please provide an example of taking advantage of this interface to implement connection pooling in a web application? I know I'm not doing it right, but cannot figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a connection once, in your constructor. If you close this connection, then this connection is closed (even if the physical handle is returned to the connection pool). Instead your `getConnection` method should do something like:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLServerException {
    return ds.getConnection();
}
```

Or better yet: just give access to the data source itself instead of introducing an unnecessary wrapper.

However as far as I know the `SQLServerXADataSource` is **not** a connection pool. It is a factory for XA connections (which you aren't using in your code example), and also extends `SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource` (which is a factory for connections to be **used** by a connection pool, not a connection pool itself).

The Java EE way is to define a JNDI datasource (which could use the `SQLServerXADataSource` or `SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource` as its factory), and then inject (or get) that data source from JNDI.

Answer (score 0):

A database might close the connection, and this is not a correct implementation of connection pooling. If you want more information about connection pooling you might read [`commons-dbcp`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) project, or [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/). Here the [example](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/blob/master/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java) of datasource that implements connection pooling.